# Можно ли в phpWord задать стиль шрифта, чтоб он появился в панели Word?

Tags: php, phpword

Я генерирую doc-файлы через phpWord. Эти файлы далее экспортируются в другие программы. И мне важно, чтобы параграфы в doc-файле стили имели название. Если помните, все эти стили с названиями расположены во вкладке Главная (см. рис). В phpWord я могу только задать название шрифта, цвет и т.п. А вот стиль создать и дать ему имя не могу? Спасибо!

[image: Вот здесь:]

Answer (score 1):

Давно с ним не работал, но в своё время это делалось так (может обновился уже):

```
$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('Your name', array('align' => 'center', 'spaceAfter' => 100));
/* например тут добавляется отступ после параграфа и выравнивание по центру */
```

Копайте в сторону метода `addParagraphStyle`

Comment: Попробую, отпишусь

Comment: Все-таки addParagraphStyle не добавляет стили в панель Microsoft Word. Это просто (как я понял) позволяет создать что-то типа переменной стиля и использовать переменную в самом коде php, чтобы постоянно не задавать параметры в виде массива, как в Вашем примере: `array('align' => 'center', 'spaceAfter' => 100)`. Продолжаю поиски...

Comment: Тут, скорее, не с документом, а шаблоном нужно провести операции